# How do you get the last entry for each month in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to filter very large tables to the latest entry per user per month. I'm not sure if I found the best way to do this. I know I "should" trust the SQL engine (snowflake) but there is a part of me that does not like the join on three columns.

Note that this is a very common operation on many big tables, and I want to use it in DBT views which means it will get run all the time.

To illustrate, my data is of this form:

`mytable`

| userId | loginDate | year | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 2021 | 1 | 41.1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-06 | 2021 | 1 | 411.1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-25 | 2021 | 1 | 251.1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 4369 |
| 2 | 2021-02-06 | 2021 | 2 | 32 |
| 2 | 2021-02-14 | 2021 | 2 | 731 |
| 3 | 2021-01-20 | 2021 | 1 | 258 |
| 3 | 2021-02-19 | 2021 | 2 | 4251 |
| 3 | 2021-03-15 | 2021 | 3 | 171 |

And I'm trying to use SQL to get the last value (by loginDate) for each month.

I'm currently doing a groupby & a join as follows:

```
WITH latest_entry_by_month AS (
    SELECT "userId", "year", "month", max("loginDate") AS "loginDate"
    FROM mytable
)

SELECT * FROM mytable NATURAL JOIN latest_entry_by_month
```

The above results in my desired output:

| userId | loginDate | year | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-25 | 2021 | 1 | 251.1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | 2021 | 1 | 4369 |
| 2 | 2021-02-14 | 2021 | 2 | 731 |
| 3 | 2021-01-20 | 2021 | 1 | 258 |
| 3 | 2021-02-19 | 2021 | 2 | 4251 |
| 3 | 2021-03-15 | 2021 | 3 | 171 |

But I'm not sure if it's optimal.

Any guidance on how to do this faster? Note that I am not materializing the underlying data, so it is effectively un-clustered (I'm getting it from a vendor via the Snowflake marketplace).

Answer (score 2):

Using `QUALIFY` and windowed function(`ROW_NUMBER`):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userId, year, month 
                          ORDER BY loginDate DESC) = 1
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I wanted :D - Didn't know you about `qualify`

Comment: I'll do some checks myself, but is there any reason to believe this is faster? Or is it just syntax

Comment: @MYK Windowed functions(ROW_NUMBER/RANK) are designed for such requirement. QUALIFY is used to filter the result of ROW_NUMBER.